# change form input through drop down box AJAX and PHP

Tags: php, xml, ajax

I've been trying to use `AJAX` and `PHP` to create a dynamically changed form where selecting an index on the drop down box automatically changes the type of input that is displayed on the form. I use a select box on the form that `onchange()` submits to the `AJAX` function. The function uses `XML` to call the `PHP` file. The the 2 types of inputs that I'm trying to switch between are a file upload and a drop down box that is populated by data that I have on a remote database. When I select the option for the file upload input, it displays fine, but the `PHP` database drop down box does not display when I select that option.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code I have right now:

**File Name: *test.php***

```
<html>
    <body>
        <head>
            <script>
                function getInputs(str) {
                    var xmlhttp;
                    if (str == "") {
                        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "";
                        return;
                    }
                    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
                        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                    xmlhttp.open("POST", "grabtest.php?q=" + str, true);
                    xmlhttp.send();
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <form action="">
            <select id='RecipeSelect' onchange='getInputs(this.value)'>
                <option selected value=''>Select</option>
                <option value='N'>New file</option>
                <option value='E'>Existing file</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <div id="display"></div>
            <br>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**File Name: *grabtest.php***

```
<?php
    $q=$_POST["q"];

    //connect to database on server
    $con=mysqli_connect("connection","loginname","password","DBname");
    //if there was an error in connecting to the database, display the error
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
    {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    if ($q=""){
        echo "";
    }
    elseif ($q="N"){
        echo "Select file to upload: <input type='file' name='newfile'>";
    }
    elseif ($q="E"){
        //creates a dropdown box where you can select desired field
        $list = mysqli_query($con, "select * from TableName");
        echo 'Recipes: <select name = "name">';
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($list))
        {
            echo '<option value = "' . $row["ID"] . '">' . $row["Recipes"] . '</option>';
        }
        echo '</select><br>';
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Submit">';
        echo '</form>';
    }

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You are using `=` (assignment), not `==` (comparison) in your if/else statements.

Comment: Hi, Jacob. Thanks for the answer! So I fixed that problem that you just pointed out, but now my form doesn't display anything at all when I select an option from the drop down box. Can you tell me if I'm still doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing `q` in the query string and using `POST`.  You need to either use `GET` or send `q`, in the send method of the XHR.